# Ruby on Rails: Find records without Sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, find

I need to find the records in the exact order as it is passed in as the search parameter.

For example, I have a string :

```
item_list = "23,12,54,45"
```

With the following query, I get records in the asc order of 'item_list' - "12,23,45,54".

```
Inventory.find(item_list.split(","))
```

How do I modify above query such that it returns the records in the same order of 'item_list'.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the largest dataset you plan on having returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, though it may only work in MySQL:

```
Inventory.where("id IN (#{item_list})").order("find_in_set(id, '#{item_list}')")
```

For smaller datasets you could let Ruby sort the results, but I think letting the database do the work for you is best for larger sets.

Answer (score 1):

Do the sorting on the client side like this:

```
ids   = item_list.split(',')
items = Inventory.find(ids).sort_by { |i| ids.index(i.id) }
```

This only uses one query and [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001481) only computes the block once for each item so that part shouldn't be that expensive. If you have a lot of items to deal with then you could easily build a Hash that maps the id to its index and use that in the `sort_by` block.

The basic idea is to sort one array using the structure of another, for example:

```
>> a = [ 23, 11, 42, 5 ]
>> b = [5, 23, 11, 42]
>> b.sort_by { |i| a.index(i) }
=> [23, 11, 42, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
item_list.split(",").collect do |item|
  Inventory.find(item)
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be collect instead of each?

Comment: @Christopher: It can be; depends on what you're trying to do. In a general case, you're probably right. I'll change it now.

Comment: @Arun: Yes, true. But it does solve the problem at hand, albeit, maybe not as efficiently as your way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 unordered_records = Inventory.where(:id => item_list)
 item_list.collect { |id| unordered_records.detect { |x| x.id == id } }
```